# How to give read_stream permission of read user feed from facebook using graph api ? I was used v2.3 version but now its not working?

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api

I want give read_stream permission for read user feed from facebook using facebook developer graph api. as per my knowledge v2.3 give read_stream permisson but not its not working.

```
var loginUrl = fb.GetLoginUrl(new
            {
                client_id = facebookapidetails.APIToken,
                client_secret = facebookapidetails.APISecret,
                redirect_uri = RedirectUri.AbsoluteUri,
                response_type = "code",
                scope = "email,offline_access,publish_stream,read_stream,manage_pages,publish_actions,read_insights" 
            });
```

Comment: read_stream is deprecated since many years, why would you want to use it? publish_stream is very old too, and so is offline_access. you should copy your code from newer sources or directly from the facebook docs.

Comment: user_posts would be the replacement for read_stream bzw. publish_actions is the replacement for publish_stream (or publish_pages if you want to post as page) and there is no replacement for offline_access.

Comment: You can not get a user’s full feed any more.

Comment: can you please provide me any link for publish_stream or any demo code which is used to read feed of user using facebook graph api so its  help me. Thank you